# Opencv - circle image warp

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I was just wondering if anyone had any ideas of how I might approach this problem. I have a camera set up looking for a circle (using Hough circle), due to the perspective however the circle it detects is of centred from the actual image.  This is because of the perspective warp from the position of the camera the "circle" is actually an ellipse.
Any help is greatly appreciated. 
(I can't post the image due to `spam measures' but it can be found [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14313753/Capture.PNG).

Comment: My question is how can I correct the prospective warp of this image so that the circle actually matches the circle on the image.

Answer (score 1):

If all your images are similar to the one you posted, you can easily apply a blob detection method:

- Binarize your image (Threshold with an appropriate value)
- Remove artifacts by an erode, then a dilation
- Find blobs
- For all the found blobs, look for center, area, moments, etc, to find the one you are interested in (there may be other smaller blobs around)
- Some statistics on the blob pixels will tell you exactly the ellipse parameters

Comment: thanks very much for your input, can i just ask you what statistics i could get from ellipse to help me correct the prospective warp.

Comment: I have computed the bounding box from the blob ellipse as you stated in your answer by, firstly finding the contours, then finding an ellipse using the fitElipse function i can find the height and width. how can i use these value to get the perspective warp?

Comment: If you know the ellipse width, height, and center, all you need is a little bit of geometry to find out the original circle. Look on Wikipedia for ellipse equation.